# Ошибка кодировки POST запроса в библиотеке xNet

Tags: c#, xnet

Добрый день, использую **сторннюю библиотеку [xNet](https://github.com/X-rus/xNet)** (удобна и хорошо документирована).

Суть проблемы: отправляю POST запрос multipart form-data на сайт (кодировка сайта Windows-1251). В параметрах запроса выставлена:

```
request.CharacterSet = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");
```

Но в итоге на сайт приходит запрос в кодировке UTF-8.

Пробовал обрабатывать текст подобным образом:

```
HttpHelper.UrlEncode("str", Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251"));
```

Но к сожалению получается вот что:

```
%C3%EE%F2%EE%E2+%EE%E1%F1%F3%E4%E8%F2%FC+%F1%F0%EE%EA%E8+%E8+%F6%E5%ED%F3.%0D%0A%0D%0A
```

т.е. в multipart form-data, на стороне сайта не срабатывает form-urlencoded.

Как можно выйти из положения? Вот примерный код того как отправляю запрос:

```
using xNet.Net;
using xNet.Collections;
using xNet.Security;
using xNet.Text;
using xNet.Threading;

using (var request = new xNet.Net.HttpRequest())
{
    request.UserAgent = xNet.Net.HttpHelper.FirefoxUserAgent();
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    request.Referer = @"http://site.ru/";
    request.CharacterSet = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251");
    //Задаем куки
    request.Cookies = cookie;

    //Параметры POST запроса
    var reqParams = new xNet.Collections.RequestParams();
    reqParams["in_office"] = "0";
    reqParams["cost"] = Cst;
    reqParams["term"] = Dt;
    reqParams["msg_body"] = xNet.Net.HttpHelper.UrlEncode(
                Text.Trim(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251"));
    reqParams["att_file"] = string.Empty;
    reqParams["cmd"] = "msg_insert";
    reqParams["topic"] = Topic.Trim();

    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
        {
            @out = request.Post(@"http://site.ru/dis/", reqParams).ToString();
        });

    //Возвращаем куки
    cookie = request.Cookies;

    reqParams.Clear();

    //Возвращаем результат
    return @out;
}
```

Comment: Откуда у вас взялся `request.CharacterSet`? В классе [`HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) такого нету.

Comment: Я использую стороннюю библиотеку xNet (удобна и хорошо документирована), вот ссылка на нее и исходники: https://github.com/X-rus/xNet

Comment: То есть это не `System.Web.HttpRequest`? Тогда спрашивайте разработчиков библиотеки, мы-то не знаем, какой у них смысл параметров.

Comment: Верно, это не System.Web.HttpRequest. К сожалению с разработчиком за несколько дней так и не смог связаться. Извините что ввел в заблуждение.

Comment: @z668: может, кто-то здесь имел опыт с их библиотекой. Мне кажется, имеет смысл указать в коде полные имена типы, с namespace'ами, во избежание путаницы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решить проблему можно так:

```
request.AddField("msg_body",
    Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1251").GetBytes("строка"));
```

Заместо байт можно передать строку, но там есть небольшой баг, из-за которого всегда используется кодировка UTF-8.

Comment: Как я понимаю Вы - автор этой библиотеки. Исправите баг с кодировкой на гитхабе? Больно библиотека понравилась.

Comment: Уже исправил и залил.